# How can I remove text headers when importing a numeric table

Tags: import

I have a file let's say 1.txt having numbers like:

```
fgdgfdg     fhdfdh
0.000105533 1.00E-04
0.222281    1.00E-04
0.444456    1.00E-04
0.666631    1.00E-04
asdas       ddfdsfsd
0.111193    0.166733
0.333369    0.166733
sadsd       dfffsas
0.777719    0.166733
```

I want to delete all this unknown string during the import process. It would be great help if you can provide me some solutions. I have tried various commands like delete, replace, cases but it doesnt work ....
thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to delete? all strings in the txt file while importing all numbers?

Answer (score 7):

As [g3kk0](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2024/g3kk0) showed *Mathematica* can easily read this data with [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Import.html).

I saved the data to a file named `TableWithText.txt` and placed it in the path given by [`Directory[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Directory.html) (which itself can be set with [`SetDirectory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDirectory.html).)

```
data = Import["TableWithText.txt", "Table"]
```

> ```
> {{"fgdgfdg", "fhdfdh"}, {0.000105533, 0.0001}, {0.222281, 0.0001}, {0.444456, 
>   0.0001}, {0.666631, 0.0001}, {"asdas", "ddfdsfsd"}, {0.111193, 0.166733}, {0.333369, 
>   0.166733}, {"sadsd", "dfffsas"}, {0.777719, 0.166733}}
> ```

From there you can strip the individual Strings with:

```
DeleteCases[data, _String, {-1}]
```

> ```
> {{}, {0.000105533, 0.0001}, {0.222281, 0.0001}, {0.444456, 0.0001}, {0.666631, 
>   0.0001}, {}, {0.111193, 0.166733}, {0.333369, 0.166733}, {}, {0.777719, 0.166733}}
> ```

Or entire rows that are composed solely of Strings:

```
DeleteCases[data, {__String}, {-2}]
```

> ```
> {{0.000105533, 0.0001}, {0.222281, 0.0001}, {0.444456, 0.0001}, {0.666631, 
>   0.0001}, {0.111193, 0.166733}, {0.333369, 0.166733}, {0.777719, 0.166733}}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your .txt file looks like the following:

[image]

you can use the `Import` function of *Mathematica* with the option `"Data"` to import your data into the list representation:

```
path="...\\..."; (*path to .txt file*)
data=Import[path, "Data"]
```

> ```
>  {{"fgdgfdg", "fhdfdh"}, {0.000105533, 0.0001}, {0.222281, 
>  0.0001}, {0.444456, 0.0001}, {0.666631, 0.0001}, {"asdas", 
>  "ddfdsfsd"}, {0.111193, 0.166733}, {0.333369, 0.166733}, {"sadsd", 
>  "dfffsas"}, {0.777719, 0.166733}}
> ```

Now you can select for specific entries. Assuming that you want to keep all entries in a one-dimensional list, I first flatten the data (`Flatten`) and then use the `Select` function to select for elements that are numeric:

```
Select[Flatten[data], NumberQ[#] &]
```

> ```
> {0.000105533, 0.0001, 0.222281, 0.0001, 0.444456, 0.0001, 0.666631,
> 0.0001, 0.111193, 0.166733, 0.333369, 0.166733, 0.777719, 0.166733}
> ```

Or using `Cases`:

```
Cases[Flatten@data, _Real]
```

> ```
> {0.000105533, 0.0001, 0.222281, 0.0001, 0.444456, 0.0001, 0.666631,
> 0.0001, 0.111193, 0.166733, 0.333369, 0.166733, 0.777719, 0.166733}
> ```